# PLA 3D Print longevity after being printed

Tags: pla

I am curious about the longevity of a PLA printed part used in a commercial application.  It would be a mounting bracket installed in an industrial enclosure.  The internal cabinet temperature would be less than 100 °F, and have an internal air circulation fan to keep the control PLC cool.

It would be in a steel enclosure, in an industrial environment, with no sunlight or UV exposure.

Would the PLA hold up over time, or have any issues with delamination or brittleness?

Comment: I'd be more concerned with the mechanical stresses involved. In particular, parts are very weak in bending forces that can cause printed layers to separate.  The environment you describe is certainly benign.

Answer (score 3):

I've had white Hatchbox PLA parts in use outside in direct or partial sun for 3+ years without issue. It may help if you paint the parts for outdoor use, but I suspect the environment you describe would be fine for several years.